# Using Float on elements

Tags: html, css

I would like for the number and the word members to be aligned.

What am I doing wrong?

***[Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/EC63P/)***

Comment: Just add float:left to your #stat-left

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:left` to id `stat-left`

Check this updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EC63P/5/)

Comment: Not quite sure how I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Now how would I would I align the word followers to the bottom of the div? :)

Comment: Add line height:35px to #stat-right. here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EC63P/26/

Comment: @Sowmya we can give them padding-top as well as to this id #stat-right p

Comment: Also why are you using these many div for the simple out put.. you can look @Tom Oakley's demo for simple html

Comment: i am also saying like this because op has defined float-left to parent div it should not like this we should not use extra markup and css always

Answer (score 0):

`#stat-left`give to`

`display:inline-block`

as like this

```
#stat-left {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[*Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/EC63P/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="float:left"` to the div with number :)

It will allow next Divs to float object from left side :)

```
<div id="connections">
                <div id="stat">
                    <div style="float:left"id="stat-left">
                    <p span class="number"> 2,476 </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="stat-right">
                    <p> Followers </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Now how would I would I align the word followers to the bottom of the div? :)

Comment: which div ? explain a bit please

Comment: <div id="stat-right" style="text-align:bottom">

Answer (score 0):

You could quite easily condense your code. Rather than using a paragraph tag, why not use a span instead? Paragraph tags are automatically block level elements, but spans are inline by default.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nckxL/).

Answer (score 0):

i tried to make a code for your with only one div and minimize code

**HTML**

```
<div id="connections">
<p class="number"> 2,476 </p>
<p class="stat-right">Followers </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#connections {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 22;
    color: #444;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.number {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
}
.stat-right {
    float:right;
    margin-top:7px;
}
```

**Check the demo** :- http://jsfiddle.net/EC63P/35/